# A question about $L^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

If we have a funtion $f:\mathbb{T}\to H$, $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} x_ke^{ikt}$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the torus and $H$ is a Hilbert space:

What is the relation between this function belonging to $L^\infty(\mathbb{T},H)$ and verifying $\sup_t\sup_{m,n}\|{\sum_{k=-m}^{n}x_ke^{ikt}}\|<\infty$?

Are they the same notions? And what happens if we pick a Banach space instead of $H$?.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think that something is missing in the definition of $f$.

Comment: _If_ I understand the notation and the question correctly then no, the two are different even when $H=\Bbb C$. There exists a continuous function $f:\Bbb T\to\Bbb C$ such that the partial sums of the Fourier series are unbounded.

Comment: Are there any relations of "content" between the properties? For example If $f$ veryfies  $\sup_t\sup_{m,n}\|{\sum_{k=-m}^{n}x_ke^{ikt}}\|<\infty$, it has to be also  in $L^\infty(\mathbb{T},H)$? The other relation of content seems to be false because of your example.